# Bad Access error in Thread with a managed object in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios7, nsmanagedobject

I have a line of code that is a table in my Sqlite DB:

```
Users *users = [[Users alloc] init];

... do some processing in a thread and other stuff

} //end function
```

But I commented everything out except the Users *users line and found out my error was related to that line when I get to the end of the function call. The error is:

```
"Thread X: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=xxxxx)
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: `*users` is an instance of `NSManagedObject` ?

Comment: Yes it is, is that bad practice or wrong?

Comment: I have a Users.h/.m file that was autogenerated by subclassing and is a table name

Comment: What do you mean by 'table name'? Aren't you using Core Data?

Comment: yes, in the desing view of the model it is called Users and has attributes and relationships

Comment: Are you trying to use an existing sqlite db with core data?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51120/discussion-between-steve-and-chris)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't create an `NSManagedObject` instance with `init`. An `NSManagedObject` is associated with an `NSManagedObjectContext` and must be created using: `initWithEntity:insertIntoManagedObjectContext:`.

[Creating and Deleting Managed Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdCreateMOs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001654-CJBDBHCB)

Comment: The real reason is I have a category called Users+Authenication which has a - (void) saveAllMyUsers... but how do I call that if I can't create an instance?

Comment: You can create an instance, just not directly. If you want to do that then you shouldn't be using Core Data. Core Data isn't simply an interface to sqlite, but an object graph manager and persistence framework. I suggest you step back and learn how Core Data works before moving forward.

Comment: The only reason I wanted the instance was to call my category function which was - (void) instead of a class function + (Users)

Comment: That too is bad practice. The `NSManagedObjectContext` is the class that handles saving changes to the data store. See [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001182-BAJCEDBI).

Comment: But I pass the context and all the details into the category to abstract it. I just need to know how to call it? Where should I put the save code, in the view controller?

Comment: You need to put it in the class that adds and removes objects from the managed object context.

Comment: You mean the auto generated ones?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51127/discussion-between-steve-and-chris)

Answer (score -1):

Any managed object belongs to a ManagedObjectContext. And any ManagedObjectContext and all the managed objects belonging to it must only ever be used in *one* thread. Otherwise, you will run into all kinds of trouble including crashes.

Comment: OP said they commented out everything except the `Users *users` line.